# ADF - Auto Create Table Option Enabled but Seeing error object already exists

Tags: azure-data-factory

We are experiencing recurrent failures on an ADF Pipeline that was running fine until 10 days ago. These pipelines are copying csv files to sql table with no schema mapping. The csv files are stored in directories in ADLS Gen2. Both directories contain csv with same names. They belong to different accounts and carry different data. I have designed nested copy activity. First I get names of folders and pass these folder names to child pipeline that copy the csv to SQL DB. The copy activity is set to parallel execution to save time. When copying to SQL DB, I have enable auto-create table activity. The first step we do before the copy activity on SQL DB is to drop all tables from the landing schema. Thus there are no tables in the DB for the raw schema at this point. When child pipelines begin copy activity, the design is such that which every pipeline starts copy activity first will begin by creating the table first.

I read the documentation on auto-create table. It clearly states that it checks if the table exists and only when object doesn't exist, it creates a table.

Thus this error message seems counter intuitive

> Inner activity name: Copy files to SQL Db, Error: *ErrorCode=SqlOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A database operation failed with the following error: 'There is already an object named 'checklists_template_items_answers' in the database.',Source=,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=There is already an object named 'checklists_template_items_answers' in the database.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=2714,Class=16,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=6,Errors=[{Class=16,Number=2714,State=6,Message=There is already an object named 'checklists_template_items_answers' in the database.,},],'*

When I re-run the pipeline without any refactoring it works fine. Each day the failure happens on a different csv. Please note it was working fine and I m seeing this failure only recently

Answer (score 0):

> *ErrorCode=SqlOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A database operation failed with the following error: 'There is already an object named 'checklists_template_items_answers' in the database.*

As per the error **checklists_template_items_answers** table is alredy exist in the database when your copy activity is executing.

Using **Pre-copy script** drop the table if it exists before copying.

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tablename;
```

[image]

Since you mentioned that you are using parallel execution to save time and have same file names in different folders, make sure that the parallel execution is not causing a race condition where multiple activities are trying to create the same table simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Pratik for taking time out to answer this question. My mind is also thinking it is a race condition; mostly it because logic!! and also it is intermittent. Like last night it ran successfully.

Do you have any design patterns to avoid race condition.

I Have used pre copy script but never when different files were writing to same table. So would the table be dropped every time there is an attempt to write into the table from a new csv.

I mean say
Folder Y  has file A
Folder Z has file A

So say File A creates tableA . THis is from folder Y. WHen ADF writes file A from Folder Z will it drop the existing table.
We don't want this behavior

Comment: This is not an answer but a comment. Please delete the answer and add a comment on the answer you are referring.

Answer (score 0):

> Looks like parallel executions resulting this intermittent issue. I would encourage you to change implementation logic in such a way that similar name file will not get copy at same time. That way this error we can avoid.

For example, may be have a log table with file names which are getting processed, If a file process state in that table is inprogress and similar file name came for copy, then we can make it wait the execution using wait activity.